# communication lost detection CAN

Tags: embedded, can-bus

I have been implementing motor control
software. This control software runs in
one microcontroller which communicates
with different microcontroller over CAN
bus. I need information about CAN "failure"
(communication lost) in the control software.
I am not sure what could be the appropriate
symptom of the CAN "failure". I have an idea that
I would check whether the CAN periphery is in the
Bus off state. If so, I would trigger some timer
and after expiration of for example 1 s I would
take the communication for lost. As soon as the 
CAN periphery transits into the Error active state
I would take the communication for secure again. 
Is it possible or anybody solve this in different 
manner? Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two completely different things to consider:

1. On the application level, does whoever you are communicating with respond in time and do they send valid data?
2. Are there hardware errors on the CAN bus?

Regarding 2), bus-off and CAN error frames are hardware errors, usually caused by rather severe things such as incorrect installation, short between CAN high/low, bad wires/connectors, EMI noise, bad/no termination, crappy signal ground and/or shield etc. These are mostly non-recoverable errors that the software can't do much about. The only thing you can do is to display some diagnostics.

Rather than messing around and examining various CAN bus errors, this kind of rugged firmware (assuming industry/automotive) should be designed so that it just checks if you have received correct data in time, as required by 1). Because that's the only thing that is relevant to you. If the bus is feeling ill, if there are error frames, but you are still receiving data - fine, just keep running for as long as you are able.

So the only thing of interest is to use a timer with a sensible timeout - depending on how fast the controlled machine is moving (500ms is a general industry standard, though faster machines might need a shorter timeout). Each time you receive a valid (series of) CAN package(s) you refresh this timer. When the timer elapses, revert to a safe state.

When/how to recover from the safe state is highly application-specific. Many safety-critical applications forbid a recovery from a critical error without an explicit command from an operator.